# is there an apps Script method to copy a column of sheet text (actually in XML format) to a text file

Tags: google-apps-script

The file is required to incorporate into a submission file as an XML  and I fail to do it programmatically although it is easily done by copy/paste.   I have saved the array to a variable and then did a driveApp to feed it into a document but it comes through as one string.   I failed to find out how to introduce the end of line code for each cell in the spreadsheet.  \n gets interpreted as text.

Comment: `Sheet.getRange(startRow,startCol,Sheet.getLastRow()-startRow+1).getDisplayValues().flat().join('\n');`

Comment: That's great. Thanks

Comment: Accepted as a good 
solution